# Yii - Get min, max of a column using active record

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am using active record. Lets call the model Product. How can i get "select min(price) from tbl_product where name like '%hair spray%'" using active record?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='MIN(price) as minprice';
$criteria->condition='name LIKE :searchTxt';
$criteria->params=array(':searchTxt'=>'%hair spray%');
$product = Product::model()->find($criteria);
```

You would just need to declare:
`public $minprice;` in your model class. (Using the above example.)

[See docs here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)